# JPQL query for parameter in list

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have two JPA-entities:

```
public class BusinessTripRequest extends StandardEntity {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "businessTripRequest", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OnDelete(DeletePolicy.CASCADE)
    @Composition
    protected List<HotelBooking> hotelBookings;
}

public class HotelBooking extends StandardEntity {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BUSINESS_TRIP_REQUEST_ID")
    protected BusinessTripRequest businessTripRequest;

    @Column(name = "JOINT_CHECK_IN")
    protected Boolean jointCheckIn;
}
```

and I tried to write a JPQL query to extract requests that:

- If the parameter is `false` then extract all requests with empty `hotelBookings` and all requests where every booking have parameter `jointCheckIn` is set to `false`
- If a parameter is `true` then extract all requests that have one or more bookings with `jointCheckIn` is set to `true`

I wrote something like this

> select e from nk$BusinessTripRequest e join e.hotelBookings hb
> where (true = ? and e.hotelBookings is not empty and hb.jointCheckIn =
> true)
> or (false = ? and e.hotelBookings is empty)

It works well when parameter is `true` because of the first condition. But I can't write a working condition for `false` parameter

Comment: could you have 2 queries and invoke one of them based on your flag parameter?

Comment: What about using `:1` instead of `?`?

Comment: @tremendous7 unfortunately, no. The parameter is used in the filter and is substituted instead of question mark. I can only change this query

Comment: @dan1st in the framework I am using, there is a question mark instead of a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution suggested from comments

```
select e
from nk$BusinessTripRequest e
where (true = ? and e.id in (select hb1.businessTripRequest.id
                         from HotelBooking hb1
                         where hb1.jointCheckIn = true))
   or (false = ? and {E}.id not in (select hb1.businessTripRequest.id
                                    from nokia$HotelBooking hb1
                                    where hb1.jointCheckIn = true))
```

Comment: The result is the same:/

Comment: @АрсланХаликов doh. what about `select e from nk$BusinessTripRequest e left join e.hotelBookings hb
where (true = ? and e.hotelBookings is not empty and hb.jointCheckIn = true)
or (false = ? and hb is null)` ?

Comment: @АрсланХаликов what about `select e
from nk$BusinessTripRequest e
where (true = ? and e.id in (select hb1.businessTripRequest.id from HotelBooking hb1 where hb1.jointCheckIn = true))
   or (false = ? and e.id not in (select hb1.businessTripRequest.id from HotelBooking hb1))` ?

Comment: Yeah, it works. But with small correction in second condition: 
`(false = ? and {E}.id not in (select hb1.businessTripRequest.id from nokia$HotelBooking hb1 where hb1.jointCheckIn = true))`
Please, edit your answer or write a new and I mark it as a solution.
Thank you

Comment: @АрсланХаликов edited the answer with your suggestions